# How do I handle win32 events from another thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, getmessage

So i wanted to handle the win32 event callbacks from a separate thread so that i can handle other stuff in the background

I've tried `std::thread` but the declaration `GetMessage(LPMSG,HWND,UINT,UINT)` will only work with a window that is on the current thread

`std::thread(EventThread) ; // i want to do this`

So, Is there any way to wait for the events and stuff from another thread? 
Any help will be appreciated !

Bye,
Samuel

Comment: What do you want to handle in the second thread? All window message or only some? What blocks you from setting up a message window in the second thread?

Comment: You could get the message in the main thread and either spawn a new thread to process or communicate between the main thread and a spawned thread.

Comment: The message-checking can't be moved to another thread, but everything else can, which makes it possible to run things in parallel like you want.

Comment: "*i wanted to handle the win32 event callbacks from a separate thread so that i can handle other stuff in the background*" - do the "other stuff" in a separate thread instead. The UI should be handled by the main thread.